# Selecting rows from a table depending on keywords in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a couple of interface elements stored in a database table which the user can filter by entering keywords (stored in another table):

Table Buttons:

```
ID   Name
 1   Button1
 2   Button2
 3   Button3
```

Table Keywords:

```
ButtonID  Keyword 
       1  Garden
       2  House
       3  Garden
       3  House
```

If the user enters `Garden`, the db returns `Button1 and Button3`.

If the user enters `House`, the db returns `Button2 and Button3`.

If the user enters `Garden AND House`, the db returns only `Button3`.

The last one is the problem, I managed to put together this query:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.Name
           , T.Type
           , T.Description
           , T.Action
           , T.Image 
FROM Tiles T 
JOIN Keywords K 
ON T.ID=K.TileID 
WHERE K.Keyword IN ('House', 'Garden')
```

Unfortunately, this query returns all three buttons with ANY of the provided keywords. But I want only the elements with all provided keywords which is `Button3`.
What should the query look like to achieve that?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: In the case of Garden AND House, what is the input you are getting in your query? Is it comma separated?

Comment: there are problem with your relational table = =that's my opinion =x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @params table (Keyword varchar(6) primary key)

insert into @params
select 'House' union all
select 'Garden'

select
    b.Name
from Keywords as k
    inner join Buttons as b on b.ID = k.ButtonID
where k.Keyword in (select Keyword from @params)
group by b.Name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from @params)
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b031c/2)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Sorry it took me so long to accept your answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Use Intersect

```
SELECT T.ID, T.Name, T.Type, T.Description, T.Action, T.Image FROM Tiles T JOIN Keywords K ON T.ID=K.TileID WHERE K.Keyword like 'House'
intersect  
SELECT T.ID, T.Name, T.Type, T.Description, T.Action, T.Image FROM Tiles T JOIN Keywords K ON T.ID=K.TileID WHERE K.Keyword like 'Garden'
```

That should get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name 
FROM tableButtons 
WHERE tableButtons.id = tableKeywords.id AND tableButtons.id 
IN 
(SELECT tableKeywords.id 
   FROM tableKeywords 
   WHERE id IN (<insert keywords here>))
```

as you may have known, the first query to be executed in the above statement will be the subquery (the inner select), it will return all the ID's of the matched keywords from the user's input, and then those ID's will be used in the outer query which in turn will match the two tables